# How to make [uc_order] token globally available?

Tags: 7, users, ubercart, tokens

In admin/config/people/accounts , I want user password in welcome mail.

Currently it is

```
username: [user:name]
password: Your password
```

I want this

```
username: [user:name]
password: [uc_order:new-password] // this token is already available in order setting page admin/store/settings/checkout
```

Now question is is there anyway to make `uc_order` token available in user account setting page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going about this the wrong way.

You can make the uc_order token globally avaialbe, but it would be a bit messy since some users wont have an order and other people have more than one order.

Instead you should use `hook_mail_alter` to actually insert the password from the order. You could search for `[uc_order:new-password]` and if found load the correct order and replace the value with the value from the order.